# Do Windows 7 Home Premium updates work under Standard User Account?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, standard-user

Do Windows 7 Home Premium updates work under Standard User Account when updates are set to "Install Updates Automatically"?

So far I found this: http://library.techguy.org/wiki/Windows_Non-Administrator_User_Account#What_can.27t_be_done_in_a_Non-Administrator_User_Account and it seems that it won't work.

I've always used Windows 7 Ultimate version myself and set it to just notify about new updates (plus my account is always a member of Administrators group). Today I am setting up laptop for a neighbor that will mostly use Standard User account under Windows 7 Home Premium and I will need to explain to them what to expect as far as Windows Updates go.

If they won't be able to install them (as article I linked to seem to suggest) - will they at least get notified so that they can login with administrator account and install updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log on as administrator on that PC, open Windows Update and select `change settings` in the left side of the window. There will be an option under "Who can install updates" to "Allow all users to install updates on this computer". This effectively makes Windows waive the UAC prompt/rules for those updates.